# Is there anyone who can offer me a solution to this error? I can't understand where I'm wrong in configuring IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

[The image is here for Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBCvo.png)
It's a problem that I can't understand in the end, which is that it always gets a ***{"error": "invalid_request"}***.

I request from Postman, using ImplicitFlow and OAuth 2.0, but I always get the same error.

I attach below the settings I made for IdentityServer4. I hope it will be useful to someone and can give me a solution.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources()
    {
        return new[] {
            new ApiResource("SkyEye.API", "SkyEye.API")
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId="ReactClient",
                ClientName="SkyEye.SPA",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:5002",
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new []{
                    "https://localhost:5002"
                },
                AllowedScopes= {
                //    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                //    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                   "SkyEye.API"
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestUser> Users()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new TestUser
            {  SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "lascodaniil",
                Password="password"
            }
        };
    }



public class Startup
{

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(Config.Users().ToList())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources());


    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your redirect URL is not valid. The URL in postman is different than the one provided in IDs configuration. The URL should be an exact match

Try changing this

```cs
RedirectUris = new List<string>
{
    "https://localhost:5002",
},
```

to this

```cs
RedirectUris = new List<string>
{
    "https://localhost:5002/connect/token",
},
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but, this isn't required,btw.

Comment: what is not required?

Comment: I just tested this on my machine and it works. Can you be more specific what doesn't work? What type of error do you get? If you want me to help you find a solution, of course...

Comment: I just get a simple error, which is described and that's it. Maybe my application doesn't have this entpoint, but I don't think so, because it's usually a dafault thing.

Do you think I should add something or not?

Comment: Well the endpoint that you'll redirect to after autorization must be exact match with the one provided in the configuration. So when you are making the authorization request the callback URL that you provide, must be the same as the one in the `Client`. Another thing to point out is, the authorization endpoint is `connect/authorize` (this is for the example in the image)

Comment: No, it doesn't work! Can you please help me somehow solve this thing?